# Facebook Messenger Chatbot for personal fan page

Tags: facebook, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I created a chatbot using Dialogflow, hooked it up as a facebook messenger chatbot for my personal fan page (A fan page for my app).

I passed through the first review process and it got approved. The next step is to "verify my business". 
I am not a business, I am just an individual developer, and I wanna allow my facebook fan page to have a chatbot that can interact with the users. I don't have a "bill" that shows my business cause I don't have on.

How do I go about that, how to enable the chatbot on a personal fan page without business verification?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would go to Facebook Support and rise your question: https://developers.facebook.com/support.

Another approach would be to change of your solution provider. Dialogflow has the disadvantage that they force you to create a Facebook App. There are solutions which does it for you, you don't need to verify the business, go through App approval, etc.

If you need free hands with custom solutions or even hold the chatbot code, than I would recommend programmer tools like:

- [amio.io](https://amio.io)
- [botkit.ai](http://botkit.ai)
- https://www.messagebird.com/en-gg/chat-api
- [recime.io](http://recime.io)
- [dev.botframework.com](https://dev.botframework.com)

If it's a simple chatbot you could take advantage of chat bot builders like:

- [chatfuel.com](http://chatfuel.com)
- [motion.ai](http://motion.ai/)
- [botsify.com](http://botsify.com)
- there are many...

> Disclaimer: I work at Amio.

Answer (score 0):

Business verification step and acceptance of supplemental terms is mandatory for messenger apps.

However, for the business verification step if you are not an actual business you can instead submit your home utility bill (with your name). I had done the same and my app was approved recently.

Comment: what if I have a page that's not under my name. My name is Marc but my facebook page is called Coptic. will that work or they have to match?

Comment: They don't need to match.

Comment: Did you get the approval @MarcY? I tried sending personal docs, but they were not accepted.

Comment: @MarcY Can you confirm the name of your Facebook page, your app name? I facing the same issue.

Comment: Any news on this?